# User and Kernel Pages

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

Does anybody know that if there is a way to find out whether a physical page is a user page or it is a kernel page. A kernel page is always accessed within kernel and not available to user processes.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, if the address in question is above the low mem range, its practically as user address (memory). The kernel can only use the low mem and it is always reserved for the kernel use. 
cat /proc/meminfo will give you the details about memory partition.

If you want to do this programmatically,

```
find_vmap_area(addr);
```

this function takes your address and returns the vmarea structure. When you get the vmarea structure, you can look for a flag

```
area->flags |= VM_USERMAP;
```

If this flag is set, its user address.

This is one way of doing it. There could be better ways, there could even be a function which does all these. Infact, i vaguely remember seeing one. Though, couldn't find now.

Comment: So, kernel can not allocate low memory to any user process. Is that true? What about if I boot a guest VM with only 128 MB ram in that case there will be no memory available for user processes.

Comment: *128MB* is physical memory; he is talking about a virtual address.

Comment: edited my answer with more details on doing it programatically.

Comment: are you looking for any more details on this? If you are satisfied and think this is a right answer, can you mark it so. might help others.

Comment: Well I dig into kernel code and find that generally user page are allocating using GFP_USER flag. But linux kernel treats GFP_KERNEL and GFP_USER same. What you are suggesting that if a user allocates some memory using vmalloc_user then it will find it out but there are several instances where user allocates memory using other primitives. Anyway your answer help me to debug some portion of my code. Thanks